# How to assign the output of a commad as a variable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, sh

**Python-3**

I have a variable which will be used in multiple location in my script. I need to assign it to a variable so i can call it any number of times.

The mail purpose is re-usability.

For EX: I run the following command in my script and expect the output to be moved into a  variable

---

Command to be run

```
aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16
```

In the output that's returned, take note of the VPC ID.

```
{
    "Vpc": {
        "VpcId": "vpc-2f09a348", 
        ...
    }
}
```

In the output i need the value of VpcId": "**vpc-2f09a348**" to be stored as a variable which can be reused in my next line in the script.

Next Line in the script:
For EX: `aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id **VpcId** --cidr-block 10.0.1.0/24`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you,
Anish

Comment: Assign it to a dict and use it.

Comment: Why are you calling the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) from Python? You should use the [official AWS Python SDK](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to call it directly, which also returns the results as a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import subprocess

text = subprocess.check_output(['aws', 'ec2', 'create-vpc', '--cidr-block',  '10.0.0.0/16'])

result = json.loads(text)
```

Comment: Please give some sort of insight into your answer for OP.

Comment: @m_callens: Answer not insightful enough?  Feel free to add your own answer or edit mine.